# two MPI broadcasts one after another

Tags: c++, mpi, broadcast

I would like to send two arrays: `double A` and `int B` using broadcast in MPI (I'm using C++). Normally, the `communicator.Bcast` blocks for readers, but not for the writer. So, if I did:

```
communicator.Bcast(A, a_len, ...)
communicator.Bcast(B, b_len, ...)
```

It could happen that some process would first retrieve the second message and things would mess up.

I wonder, what is the good, clean solution for that problem? Should I use derived datatypes/MPI_Pack? It seems ugly. Can I somehow force usage of TAGs in broadcast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MPI guarantees that collective calls on a communicator are processed in the order they are issued. So no, the readers will not retrieve the second message first - that example is save.

FYI, the MPI C++ interface has been deprecated - it's better to use the C API directly for new code.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the guarantee is there only as long as the sequence of collective calls is the same in all ranks. Otherwise the behaviour is undefined.